# How do I test for time heterogeneity in RSiena?

Tags: r

How can I test for time differences in the parameters of my model if I have multiple panels?

For example, I use the stock dataset from RSiena:

```
d <- sienaDataCreate(sienaDependent(array(c(s501, s502, s503), dim=c(50, 50, 3))))
e <- getEffects(d)
e <- includeEffects(e, transTrip)
ans <- siena07(sienaAlgorithmCreate(nsub=4, n3=1000), data=d, effects=e, batch=TRUE)
```

I want to see whether the `transTrip` effect differs from period 1 to period 2.

Answer (score 1):

All that is required is to pass the `ans` into the `sienaTimeTest` function:

```
tt <- sienaTimeTest(ans)
summary(tt)
```

This provides a nice test for whether there is any time heterogeneity in the parameters.